# Why is `subprocess.check_output()` showing me unwanted output?

Tags: python-3.x, stdout

If you type `curl ipinfo.io/ip` in the terminal you will get your public IP.

I want to get it with Python3. I am using the following call

```
try:
    s=subprocess.check_output(['curl', 'ipinfo.io/ip'])
except:
    raise
print('ip = %s'%s.decode('utf-8'))
```

anyway, I get extra output in the standard output. Why?